# Django modify or reset migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I wanted to edit my Models who was working fine(Data was stored with no problem). So I edited the models class, and I runned the `manage.py makemigrations` command and I think it bugged my project. Even If I delete what I added on my models, it not working like before. Thanks for helping.

ps: I dont care about losing the current data that I have saved on my DATABASE

the error when i run the migrations command: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (gendernumber) specified for Post`

models.py (BEFORE modifying)

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

models.py (AFTER the edit)

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):

    THE_GENDER = [
        ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
        ("Madame", "Madame")
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class post_form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(post_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["name", "email", "gender" "number"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you dont care about the data:

1) Drop the database. Create it again. Give and flush privileges to django.

2) Erase all migrations folders, but not the **init**.py file, (or just run this in the proyect folder)

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

3) run makemigrations and migrate.

EDIT: check forms.py:

> fields = ["name", "email", "gender" "number"]

here is your problem, gender and number must be separated by a comma.

```
fields = ["name", "email", "gender", "number"]
```

---

Also, I added the command of Reinstate Monica's comment. Thanks.

Comment: You should add `find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -delete` so that the cached migration files are also deleted.  The cached files sometimes cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted the migrations folder and runned your commands. But when I make manage.py makemigrations its say: No changes detected, And when i go to my admin page, i still can see the SMS-POST data, but give me error when i click on it

Answer (score 1):

put gender choices outside the class.

```
THE_GENDER = [
    ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
    ("Madame", "Madame")
]
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can delete migration files and data base and make migrations again if you really dont care about stored data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, did worked either, Im trying to delete magrations files and data but look like I faced error, problems, im working on it

Comment: Make sure migration and database files are not opened anywhere and delete migration files not folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite, then delete the file. Delete the files in migrations except init. In pycache delete all except init also.